# Get window height on mobile devices (especially iPhones) without using jQuery

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, html, mobile

All the answers on SO for fetching the device's height seem based on jQuery. We need something in pure JavaScript before the jQuery code loads.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
document.documentElement.clientHeight
```

There are a number of other methods, too: http://responsejs.com/labs/dimensions/

Comment: oops, sorry, we need the viewport, but it seems like your link contains the answer anyway. thanks!

Comment: Can't believe how rare this (correct) answer is for viewport height

Answer (score 14):

May be a little late, but use `window.screen.height`

Comment: because `window.screen.height` returns screen height, not the browser viewport height

Comment: This doesn't consider the height in use by the address bar / navigation.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, **$(window).height();** does the job. However, on iOS, it gives wrong results because of the toolbars, same as  **$(window).outerHeight();**. The right value to use is **window.outerHeight**.

Try this :

```
(typeof window.outerHeight != 'undefined')?Math.max(window.outerHeight, $(window).height()):$(window).height()
```