# jQuery detect scroll reach bottom not working on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I' trying to detect when user scroll down bottom of a web page to load show some contents when user scroll to near bottom,

i use below function which works perfectly on all desktop web browsers, but its not worked on mobile browsers.

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery(document).scroll(function () {
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height() > jQuery(document).height() -100) {
           //show contents
            alert('near bottom')
    }
  });
});
```

this is my working website i applied above http://discount.today/

when scroll down it shows some extra products, it working on normal browsers but not on mobile browsers,

can anyone help me to fix this issue please. i tried lots of solution which is on internet but no luck, thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243571/get-window-height-on-mobile-devices-especially-iphones-without-using-jquery

Comment: your exact script worked when I opened http://imgecho.com/aaa.html Make sure the other scripts are not preventing the functionality

Comment: @Mindeater i applied (typeof window.outerHeight != 'undefined')?Math.max(window.outerHeight, $(window).height()):$(window).height() but didn't worked

Comment: @SaumilSoni scroll function is working but the problem with detecting the end of page

Answer (score 3):

Here is solution

```
 if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 100) {
        alert("bottom detected");
}
```

add -100 so this will work on mobile

Answer (score 2):

Mobile webs are different then desktop webs. The reason is very simple, The margins and padding are different.

Your website probably doesn't know how to detect that a change has occurred when running on mobile so as far as the web's concern, It didn't reach the bottom.

You need to use CSS 3 maybe or even jquery, to signal the web that a change in platform was made, The site is now smaller and so the bottom of the page.

As for how to do that, I am short in suggestions. This is the general direction though.

Comment: https://github.com/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll detect the bottoms and load contents on every browser, i think there have a way still searching that

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution which will work on every device:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  var d = document.documentElement;
  var offset = d.scrollTop + window.innerHeight;
  var height = d.offsetHeight;
  console.log('offset = ' + offset);
  console.log('height = ' + height);
  if (offset >= height) {
    console.log('at the bottom');
  }
}
```